# Negative values for OLS variance

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares

I am currently writing some code which performs regression and have noticed that when I calculate variance of $c\hat{\beta}$ I am sometimes on some datasets getting negative values.

The variance is given as $c'(X'X)^{-1}c\frac{e'e}{n - p}$ where $c$ is a vector representing the contrast to be tested, $X$ is the design matrix, $e$ is a vector of residuals and $n$ is the number of datapoints and $p$ is the number of parameters (including an intercept).

I want to compute a T statistic but this involves square rooting the variance and is failing in some cases when the variance is negative. My question is could there be a mathematical/statistical reason why I am having this issue? And if so why/why not? (or should I be asking this instead on StackOverflow?)

My datasets vary in size and negative values appear to occur the most frequently when $n$ is only just greater than $p$ (e.g. when $n=p+1,n=p+2,... $etc ).

Comment: My guess is that when, $n\approx p$ invertability of matrix becomes numerically unstable due to your choice of how to evaluate the expression for the variance, have you inspected the behavior of your matrix inversions? Any warnings?

Comment: My question would be, why are you writing your own code to do this?  Nearly every modern language has statistical packages capable of performing regression.

Comment: Are you calculating a generalized inverse?  Also, are you rounding your results?

Comment: My bet is that you are not calculating a generalized inverse and if $(X'X)$ your matrix is singular and your program is outputting -1 or some other garbage answer.  Are you able to share your code or data?

Comment: The only method of obtaining a negative variance is from a purely imaginary standard deviation as $i^2=-1$.

Comment: @Carl Experience teaches that there are many other ways to compute a negative quantity for a variance.  Some variances are computed as differences of two positive values and floating point error is enough to create a negative result in the computer.  The comments preceding yours suggest plausible mechanisms for the formula in the question to produce negative values, depending on how the calculation is performed.

Comment: The reason I am calculating X'X inverse directly is application driven and cannot be done in the standard manner. I use np.linalg.inv for inverting and do this by broadcasting across a 3d matrix of many different analyses at once. I have a 3d array of size n_a by n_p by n_p where n_a is the number of analyses and each n_p by n_p is an XtX matrix.

Comment: You really, really don't want to do it that way.  Instead use a stable method of solving the equation $X^\prime X y = c$ for $y$ (and then premultiply that by $c^\prime$). That will be much more sparing in its use of computing resources, too, making it hard to understand how any application could force you to use a poor algorithm.

Comment: Without going into details, my application doesn't allow me Y, only XtY, YtY and XtX.

Comment: Apologies my notation in the previous comment should have been $p$ not $n_p$

Comment: I get no warnings and as far as I am aware I am not rounding.

Comment: @whuber Sure, one can arrive at a negative variance by $n$-tuple methods. However, each negative variance corresponds to a purely imaginary number deviation, i.e., a characteristic of a non-real solution; having no real world significance as I understand it.

Comment: @Carl IMHO, that observation sheds no light on the question, because these negative variances have not arisen through squaring.  All you assert is the irrelevant fact that negative numbers have no real square roots.

Comment: @whuber Standard deviation is a distance, variance is an area. Areas can indeed be measured by tiling or weighing cutouts but neither measure cares how it arose. I posited the sublime as rediculous, and you the rediculous as sublime.

Comment: I suspect that you are looking for $\operatorname{var}\left(c'\widehat\beta\right)$ where $c\in\mathbb R^{p\times1}$ is a contrast. That variance would be $$ c'(X'X)^{-1}c \frac{\operatorname{var}(e'e)}{n-p} $$

Comment: Hi @MichaelHardy , Apologies I was under the impression it should be:

$$ c'(X'X)^{-1}c \frac{e'e}{n-p} $$

Is this incorrect?

Comment: @JDoe2 : What I should have written above is $$ c'(X'X)^{-1} \frac{\operatorname E(e'e)}{n-p}, $$ with expected value rather than variance. This is the same as what is usually written as $$ 
\sigma^2 c'(X'X)^{-1}c $$ where $\sigma^2$ is the error variance. But what you wrote is a random variable, whereas the variance should be a constant.